# Resize views, on making other views invisible

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity that has a linear layout, and a footer:
The structure is somewhat like this :

< LinearLayout >
   ...
   ...
   < LinearLayout >
       android:id="@+id/main_view"
       ...
       ...
   < /LinearLayout >
   < LinearLayout >
       android:id="@+id/footer"
       ...
       ...
   < /LinearLayout >
< /LinearLayout >

I am making the footer invisible on a certain condition.
But I want to make the main_view, resize to take the space made
available by making the footer invisible.
Is there any way to do it?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on your `View`.  When visibility is set to `VISIBLE` it is drawn, when set to `INVISIBLE` it is not drawn but still measured takes up space on the screen.  When it is set to `GONE` it is not drawn and not measured.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your using `View.INVISIBLE` constant, which hides a view but keeping the space it used. You may use `View.GONE` instead.